# Clearing CompositeDisposible in ondestroy?

Tags: android, rx-java

All the examples I see of CompositeDisposible clear it in onDestroy. Why does this not cause memory leaks since onDestroy is not guaranteed to happen? I thought all register/unregister logic was supposed to be done in onStart/onStop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time `onDestroy()` isn't guaranteed to happen is when your entire process is being destroyed - as per the [Who Lives and who dies? blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f), Android only kills your app at the process level. At that point, **everything** in memory related to your process is going to be cleared, so there's no memory leak possible.